# for f/ tokens in sql

Tags: sql, substring, token

I have a primary key that consists of numbers letters and dashes.
For example 7223-03-PINK

As new records are created the 1st block of numbers (7223) will keep incrementing by +1.
while the 2nd and 3rd block (03-PINK) will stay the same.

Over time as records are added to the table the 1st block of the pkey will eventually become a 5 number digit instead of the current 4 digits.

I want to select the 1st block of the pkey.  I don't want to use

> SUBSTRING(pkey,1,**4**)

because eventually I will have to change this formula to

> SUBSTRING(pkey,1,**5**).

Is there anything in SQL that allows would allow me to select only the 1st token? Maybe something equivalent to a FOR /F "tokens= 1 ".... in CMD?

I am trying to do this in SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up its position and read to it;

```
  SUBSTRING(pkey, 1, CHARINDEX('-', pkey, 1) - 1)
```

You could also perhaps consider having the leading integer part in its own integer (identity?) column.